# Взаимодействие php и c++

Tags: php, c++

Нужно отправить набор данных json из php-скрипта в программу с++ и получить результат json. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вот тут посмотри решение - [Communication between PHP and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44566268/4772782)

Comment: Программа находится у вас на сервере? Или вы хотите чтобы пользователь получал у себя в программе, которые будет отдавать PHP?

Comment: Взаимодействие с программой на С++ ничего не отличается от взаимодействия с программой на любом другом языке. Собственно для php совсем не важно, на чем написана другая программа.

Comment: Скрипт и программа будут находиться на одном сервере (в смысле на одной linux-машине). Мне симпатичен вариант через unix-сокет, чтобы программа на С++ его прослушивала, что-то вроде с++ сервера, такое возможно? А php-скрипт будет сбрасывать данные на этот сокет и получать из него результат. И как такой вариант в плане скорости по сравнению с другими вариантами? Уже предлагали разделяемую память, stdin/stdout, файлы, бд, exec, passthru.